How to useAutocomplete in a Slide?
I have a useAutocomplete which I implement inside a Slide MUI Component:
<Slide
  in={isOpen}
  timeout={{ enter: 300, exit: 200 }}
  mountOnEnter
  unmountOnExit
>
  <div {...getRootProps()}>
    <TextField
      variant="outlined"
      label="search"
      size="small"
      value={searchInput}
      autoFocus
      onChange={(e) => setSearchInput(e.target.value)}
      InputLabelProps={{ ...getInputLabelProps() }}
      inputProps={{ ...getInputProps() }}
      InputProps={{
        endAdornment: (
          <InputAdornment position="end">
            <SearchIcon />
          </InputAdornment>
        ),
      }}
    />
    <List {...getListboxProps()}>{optionsList}</List>
  </div>
</Slide>

I get this error while isOpen (prop) is false:

Unable to find the input element. It was resolved to null while an HTMLInputElement was expected. Instead, useAutocomplete expects an input element. Make sure you have bound getInputProps correctly and that the normal ref/effect resolutions order is guaranteed.*

How can i resolve this error, while keeping the animation Slide provides?

First, please remark that some APIs that you are using are deprecated. Refer to this
so, this part of your code should now be, with slotProps a prop of TextField:
slotProps={{
  inputLabel: { ...getInputLabelProps() },
  htmlInput: { ...getInputProps() },
  input: {
    endAdornment: (
      <InputAdornment position="end">
        <SearchIcon />
      </InputAdornment>
    ),
  },
}}

Then, I have checked the error and tested the rendering. The reason could be that the component starts rendering on the server (if you are using Server Components, for example) so the ref has issues bounding. instead you may have to move your component to a client file and importing it with SSR unset
